# complex equations taylor expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

in class i was asked to expand $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$ into a series about the point $z_0 =i$
i solved it in two different ways and got two different answers, i would like to know where my error is

(1) using succesive derivatives:
$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}, f^{(n)}(z) = \frac{(-1)^n*{(n+1)}!}{z^{n+2}}$

plug that into the series formula:
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(i)}{n!}*(z-i)^n$

$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{i^{n+2}}*(z-i)^n$

(2) - using the derivative of f(z):

$ \frac{1}{z^2} = (\frac{-1}{z})' = -( \frac{1}{i+z-i})' =(i\sum_{n=0}^\infty i^n(z-1)^n)' =(\sum_{n=0}^\infty i^{n+1}(z-1)^n)'$

now we derive by parts and we get
$\frac{1}{z^2}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty i^{n+1}n(z-1)^{n-1} $

how come my two answers dont match up?

Comment: Your method is correct, but unfortunately the second power series expansion contains error. Otherwise you will get the same result.

Comment: The second power series is centered wrongly.

And to get rid of the negative index, you should treat the constant in the series separately, then differentiate it.